# strange behavior of the fscanf function

Tags: matlab, scanf

I am trying to read the information contained in a small configuration file with Matlab's fscanf function. The content of the file is;

```
YAcex: 1.000000
YOx: 1.000000
KAce: 1.000000
```

The matlab code used to parse the file is;

```
fh = fopen('parameters', 'r');
fscanf(fh, 'YAcex: %f\n')
fscanf(fh, 'YOx: %f\n')
fscanf(fh, 'KAce: %f\n')
fclose(fh);
```

When this script is invoked, only the "YAcex" line is read correctly; fscanf returns `[]` for the two other lines. If the YOx and KAce lines are switched (KAce before YOx), all lines are read correctly by fscanf.

Can someone explain this behavior?

**supplementary information:** The linefeeds in the input file are simple linefeed (\n character, without \r character).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you only want to read one value per call to [`fscanf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html), but by default it tries to read as many values as possible. Note this excerpt from the documentation:

> The `fscanf` function reapplies the format throughout the entire file and positions the file pointer at the end-of-file marker. If `fscanf` cannot match `formatSpec` to the data, it reads only the portion that matches and stops processing.

This means the first call correctly reads the first line of the file, but then tries to read the next line as well, finding no *exact* match to its [format specifier](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html#inputarg_formatSpec). It finds a *partial* match for the next line, where the first `Y` of `YOx:` matches the beginning of `YAcex:` in the format specifier. This partial match places the file pointer directly *after* the `Y` in `YOx:`, causing the next call to `fscanf` to fail since it is starting at the `Ox: ...`. We can illustrate this with [`ftell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ftell.html):

```
fh = fopen('parameters', 'r');
fscanf(fh, 'YAcex: %f\n');
ftell(fh)

ans =

    18    % The "O" is the 18th character in the file
```

When you switch the `YOx:` and `KAce:` lines, a partial match of the next line doesn't happen any more, so the file pointer ends up at the *beginning* of the next line every time and all the reads are successful.

So, how can you get around this? One option is to always specify the [size argument](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html#inputarg_sizeA) so `fscanf` doesn't reapply the format specifier unnecessarily:

```
fh = fopen('parameters', 'r');
fscanf(fh, 'YAcex: %f\n', 1);
fscanf(fh, 'YOx: %f\n', 1);
fscanf(fh, 'KAce: %f\n', 1);
fclose(fh);
```

Another option is to do this all in one line:

```
fh = fopen('parameters', 'r');
values = fscanf(fh, 'YAcex: %f\n YOx: %f\n KAce: %f\n');
fclose(fh);
```

And `values` will be a 3-by-1 array containing the 3 values from the file.

Comment: According to the OP, his  code reads correctly when YOx and KAce lines are switched. Any insight on that?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this behaviour on 2014b @Sarder Usama

Comment: Try switching those lines in both the text file and MATLAB script. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azdmh.jpg

Comment: @SardarUsama: Figured it out. It's kind of obscure. I don't think I've come across it before.

Answer (score 1):

As you already realized, \r or \r\n could cause this kind of behavior. The likely reason is similar to that, for example, there is some invisible characters like space somewhere. You can debug this by reading all as uint8, and take a look at the location where problem occurs:

```
u8 = fread(fh, inf, '*uint8')';
```

One stupid way to avoid this kind of issue is to read all as char, and search each keyword:

```
fh = fopen('parameters');
ch = fread(fh, inf, '*char')'; % read all as char
fclose(fh);

YAcex = regexp(ch, '(?<=YAcex:\s?)[\d\.]+', 'match', 'once'); % parse YAcex
```

You can parse others accordingly. The advantage of this is that it is less sensitive to a space somewhere, and the order of parameters does not matter.

Comment: Although this is only a neat solution for small files, as repeatedly regexp-ing a large file for keywords is a slow way to parse when you knew they were on individual lines anyway!

Comment: @Wolfie very true. The other answer is perfect IMO. I am going to delete my answer if you feel appropriate.

Comment: Up to you, your solution is valid, it's probably just not the *best* solution to this question :)